# How to Define Virtual Host Settings on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost

I use Ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop.

I added the following to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/square/public"
ServerName square.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

And restarted the apache.

I go to http://square.localhost/ and it gives an error telling server not found.

Could anyone tell me how to define virtual host settings on Ubuntu please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set up square.localhost to have a DNS or hosts file entry so that it resolves to the IP address of your lap-top ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not modify the httpd.conf file, but add a new conf file inside /etc/apache2/sites-available/

This tutorials should clarify you how it works:

http://www.debuntu.org/2006/02/22/7-virtual-hosting-using-apache-2

http://brucewampler.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/adding-virtual-hosts-to-ubuntu-apache/

Comment: I tried both, but it does not work.